# Setting ONLY the Activity Background and not the Action Bar Background

Tags: android

I would like to set the background of my activity to an image without setting the ActionBar background to the same image.  I started with a "Hello, world" application with EditText, Button and an ActionBar and the following styles added...

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg20140804_090625_640_960</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Here is the application manifest...

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.company.android.mysecondapplication.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

The problem I am seeing is that the background image is shown in the ActionBar (distorted).  I would like the ActionBar to be semi-transparent and for the background of the Activity to show through.

This is what it looks like, notice the ActionBar background.  Also notice the icons are way over to the left when normally (i.e., without the custom style), they would be to the right.

[image]

Lastly, if you change the styles to the following, the application looks like the tutorial.

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>

</resources>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the background image to the layout of your Activity and not to the Theme, that will result in only the Activity having the image as the background.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:background="@drawable/bg20140804_090625_640_960" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I changed the LinearLayout as you suggest and removed the background property from my style.  But the ActionBar is not transparent.

Comment: I fixed my non-transparent ActionBar.  I needed to define a transparent color and reference that as @color/my_color.  I was using #44000000 directly instead of a @color/.  Newbie mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
    <item name="android:background">@color/your_color</item>
```

with

```
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/your_color</item>
```

You can use `@drawable/your_drawable` of course.